# Catia, CREO watermark

Tags: watermark, cad, catia

Is it possible to watermark a CAD model created in CATIA or CREO? I am new to this area and would like to watermark my CAD files (some in CATIA, some in CREO) so that if it is leaked, I will know its my file.
It should be a dynamic watermark with my company name & user who download the file from my server.

Please help.

Comment: This question is unsuitable for stackoverflow.

Comment: I disagree, it is clearly a development based question, however it could be edited to be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

The CAD Model once produced and loaded to your server for download, is a static, binary file. It CAN be watermarked by the authoring software, but these watermarks will be static as well.

A dynamic watermark is possible with image files such as .jpg and .png formats when accessed using a server side processing language such as PHP and GD. See for more info:  http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php

What you are looking for would be a way for an on-access application on the server side to "unpack" the CAD binary (.dwg?) - embed a watermark, and then deliver the contents to the downloader.

I found this GitHub repository that can watermark PDF files using PHP - https://github.com/binarystash/pdf-watermarker - If something like this exists for .dwg format I am unaware of it's existence.

Short answer: I don't think it's possible without finding, or writing a specific piece of software for this purpose, but it is theoretically possible.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a prt or catpart file I don't think you can watermark it. I am not even aware of static watermarking for prt files.

However, you can try this in creo (not sure about CATIA)
Create two parameters say, COMPANY_NAME and DOWNLOADER_NAME and add some placeholder values as {comp_name} and {down_name}

[image: Parameter]

Then before a user downloads the file edit the binary file search for {comp_name} and {down_name} and replace them with your company name and downloader name. I am showing how the binary file looks like in notepad++, so that you may get an idea

[image: np++ edit]

Now if a file gets leaked you can take a look at its parameters and know who downloaded it(assuming the person didn't change the parameter manually)

**But remember** that the no of characters before and after editing should be the same. So if you want to have a longer name use a longer placeholder (and if you get a shorter name fill it up with blank spaces).

I hope this was helpful